# TEXT INPUT RETURNING "" (empty string)

Tags: javascript, html, forms, object, input

I've been trying to make **a web that should work like a virtual library** where yo add or delete the books you had read o are willing to read. The idea was to set a button that opens up a kind of **form where you fill de necessary info and press the "Submit"** Button so the code could **create an object and push it to an array** with the info of the book. but every time I try to debug the code **my text inputs from the HTML returns "" asi if the fields where empty**, when they are not. I really don't get to catch where the problem is, since I've tried to change various things and nothing seemed to work, and also I had already coded the same kind of operation on other projects and it worked just fine. So I would really apreciate your help, thank you ! (PD: Im not sure that the object constructor and the way I push objects to the array are well implemented, but thats something Im willing to fix on my own later if I neeed to.)

```js
const myLibrary =[];
const titleInput = document.getElementById('title').value;
const authorInput = document.getElementById('author').value;
const pagesInput = document.getElementById('pages').value;
const readInput = document.getElementById('read').value;
const form = document.getElementById('form');
const newBook = document.getElementById('newbook')
const submitBook = document.getElementById('submit');
const iconclose = document.getElementById('iconclose');



newBook.addEventListener('click', function(){

    form.style.display = 'inline';
    newBook.hidden= true;
})

iconclose.addEventListener('click', function(){

    form.style.display = 'none';
    newBook.hidden = false;
})

submitBook.addEventListener('click',addBook);

function addBook(){

    let newObject = nuevo(titleInput, authorInput, pagesInput, readInput);

    return myLibrary.push(newObject);


    
}

function nuevo(titleInput, authorInput, pagesInput, readInput){
    
        this.title = titleInput,
        this.author = authorInput,
        this.pages = pagesInput,
        this.read = readInput
    
};
```

```css
#form{

    background-color: #E5E5F7;
    opacity: 0.5;
    background: radial-gradient(circle, transparent 20%, #E5E5F7 20%, #E5E5F7 80%, transparent 80%, transparent), radial-gradient(circle, transparent 20%, #E5E5F7 20%, #E5E5F7 80%, transparent 80%, transparent) 80px 80px, linear-gradient(#0713fa 6.4px, transparent 6.4px) 0 -3.2px, linear-gradient(90deg, #0713fa 6.4px, #E5E5F7 6.4px) -3.2px 0;
    background-size: 160px 160px, 160px 160px, 80px 80px, 80px 80px;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 1.5fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1.5fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    gap: 0px 0px;
    grid-template-areas:
    "add-book-form add-book-form add-book-form add-book-form"
    "title-label title-label title-label title-label"
    "title-input title-input title-input title-input"
    "author-label author-label author-label author-label"
    "author-input author-input author-input author-input"
    "pages-label pages-label pages-label pages-label"
    "pages-input pages-input pages-input pages-input"
    "readit-label readit-label readit-label readit-label"
    "readit-input readit-input readit-input readit-input";

    width: 50vw;
    position: absolute;
    left: 25vw;
    border-radius: 30px;
    height: 96%;
    box-shadow: -1px 14px 25px -2px rgba(71,71,71,0.47);
    overflow: hidden;
}
#formtit{
    grid-area: add-book-form;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    padding-left: 8vw;
    width: inherit;
    font-size: 4vw;
}
#titlelabel{
    grid-area: title-label;
    padding-left: 3vw;
    font-size: 3vw;
}

#title{
    grid-area: title-input;
    border-radius: 20px;
    width: 47vw;
    height: 3vw;
    box-shadow: -1px 3px 14px -2px rgb(71 71 71 / 47%);
}
#authorlabel{
    grid-area: author-label;
    padding-left: 3vw;
    font-size: 3vw;
}
#author{

    grid-area: author-input;border-radius: 20px;
    width: 47vw;
    height: 3vw;
    box-shadow: -1px 3px 14px -2px rgb(71 71 71 / 47%);
}
#pageslabel{

    grid-area: pages-label;
    padding-left: 3vw;
    font-size: 3vw;
}
#pages{

    grid-area: pages-input;
    border-radius: 20px;
    width: 47vw;
    height: 3vw;
    box-shadow: -1px 3px 14px -2px rgb(71 71 71 / 47%);
}
#readlabel{

    grid-area: readit-label;
    padding-left: 3vw;
    font-size: 3vw;
}
#read{

    grid-area: readit-input;
}
#submit{

    grid-area: submit-button;
    grid-area: submit-button;
    position: absolute;
    left: 40%;
    top: 80%;
    height: 10%;
    width: 20%;
    border-radius: 20px;
}
#iconclose{
    position: absolute;
    padding-left: 94%;
    padding-top: 3%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Library2</title>
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css">
</head>
<body>
    <button id="newbook" >Add newbook</button>
    <div style="display: none;" id="form">
        <img id="iconclose" src="images/bx-window-close.svg">
        <h2 id="formtit" >Add new book</h2>
        <label id="titlelabel" for="title">Title:</label><br>
            <input type="text" id="title" name="title" placeholder="Name of the book">
        <label id="authorlabel" for="author">Author:</label><br>
            <input type="text" id="author" name="author" placeholder="Name of the author"><br>
        <label id="pageslabel" for="pages">Pages:</label><br>
            <input type="number" id="pages" name="pages" placeholder="Number of pages you had read so far"><br>
        <label id="readlabel" for="read">Have you read it already?</label><br>
            <input type="checkbox" id="read" name="read" value=""><br>
        <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Submit Book">
    </div> 
    <script defer src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You need the submit click event to occur before you get the values. Currently you get values only on page load...before user has entered anything

Comment: For example, `document.getElementById('title').value` should be inside of the `addBook` function so that it gets the value _after_ you click submit

Comment: Thank you ! I'll try that as soon as a possible and let you know how it goes !

Answer (score 0):

You have few things that you need to change to make your code works:
first remove the `value` here:

```
const titleInput = document.getElementById('title');
const authorInput = document.getElementById('author');
const pagesInput = document.getElementById('pages');
const readInput = document.getElementById('read');
```

then you need to refactor the nuevo function to return an object like this:

```
function nuevo(){
    
      return{ title: titleInput.value,
        autho : authorInput.value,
        pages :pagesInput.value,
        read : readInput.value}
        
    
};
```

```js
const myLibrary =[];
const titleInput = document.getElementById('title');
const authorInput = document.getElementById('author');
const pagesInput = document.getElementById('pages');
const readInput = document.getElementById('read');
const form = document.getElementById('form');
const newBook = document.getElementById('newbook')
const submitBook = document.getElementById('submit');
const iconclose = document.getElementById('iconclose');



newBook.addEventListener('click', function(){

    form.style.display = 'inline';
    newBook.hidden= true;
})

iconclose.addEventListener('click', function(){

    form.style.display = 'none';
    newBook.hidden = false;
})

submitBook.addEventListener('click',addBook);

function addBook(){

    let newObject = nuevo();
console.log(newObject);
    return myLibrary.push(newObject);


    
}

function nuevo(){
    
      return{ title: titleInput.value,
        autho : authorInput.value,
        pages :pagesInput.value,
        read : readInput.value}
        
    
};
```

```css
#form{

    background-color: #E5E5F7;
    opacity: 0.5;
    background: radial-gradient(circle, transparent 20%, #E5E5F7 20%, #E5E5F7 80%, transparent 80%, transparent), radial-gradient(circle, transparent 20%, #E5E5F7 20%, #E5E5F7 80%, transparent 80%, transparent) 80px 80px, linear-gradient(#0713fa 6.4px, transparent 6.4px) 0 -3.2px, linear-gradient(90deg, #0713fa 6.4px, #E5E5F7 6.4px) -3.2px 0;
    background-size: 160px 160px, 160px 160px, 80px 80px, 80px 80px;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 1.5fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1.5fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    gap: 0px 0px;
    grid-template-areas:
    "add-book-form add-book-form add-book-form add-book-form"
    "title-label title-label title-label title-label"
    "title-input title-input title-input title-input"
    "author-label author-label author-label author-label"
    "author-input author-input author-input author-input"
    "pages-label pages-label pages-label pages-label"
    "pages-input pages-input pages-input pages-input"
    "readit-label readit-label readit-label readit-label"
    "readit-input readit-input readit-input readit-input";

    width: 50vw;
    position: absolute;
    left: 25vw;
    border-radius: 30px;
    height: 96%;
    box-shadow: -1px 14px 25px -2px rgba(71,71,71,0.47);
    overflow: hidden;
}
#formtit{
    grid-area: add-book-form;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    padding-left: 8vw;
    width: inherit;
    font-size: 4vw;
}
#titlelabel{
    grid-area: title-label;
    padding-left: 3vw;
    font-size: 3vw;
}

#title{
    grid-area: title-input;
    border-radius: 20px;
    width: 47vw;
    height: 3vw;
    box-shadow: -1px 3px 14px -2px rgb(71 71 71 / 47%);
}
#authorlabel{
    grid-area: author-label;
    padding-left: 3vw;
    font-size: 3vw;
}
#author{

    grid-area: author-input;border-radius: 20px;
    width: 47vw;
    height: 3vw;
    box-shadow: -1px 3px 14px -2px rgb(71 71 71 / 47%);
}
#pageslabel{

    grid-area: pages-label;
    padding-left: 3vw;
    font-size: 3vw;
}
#pages{

    grid-area: pages-input;
    border-radius: 20px;
    width: 47vw;
    height: 3vw;
    box-shadow: -1px 3px 14px -2px rgb(71 71 71 / 47%);
}
#readlabel{

    grid-area: readit-label;
    padding-left: 3vw;
    font-size: 3vw;
}
#read{

    grid-area: readit-input;
}
#submit{

    grid-area: submit-button;
    grid-area: submit-button;
    position: absolute;
    left: 40%;
    top: 80%;
    height: 10%;
    width: 20%;
    border-radius: 20px;
}
#iconclose{
    position: absolute;
    padding-left: 94%;
    padding-top: 3%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Library2</title>
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css">
</head>
<body>
    <button id="newbook" >Add newbook</button>
    <div style="display: none;" id="form">
        <img id="iconclose" src="images/bx-window-close.svg">
        <h2 id="formtit" >Add new book</h2>
        <label id="titlelabel" for="title">Title:</label><br>
            <input type="text" id="title" name="title" placeholder="Name of the book">
        <label id="authorlabel" for="author">Author:</label><br>
            <input type="text" id="author" name="author" placeholder="Name of the author"><br>
        <label id="pageslabel" for="pages">Pages:</label><br>
            <input type="number" id="pages" name="pages" placeholder="Number of pages you had read so far"><br>
        <label id="readlabel" for="read">Have you read it already?</label><br>
            <input type="checkbox" id="read" name="read" ><br>
        <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Submit Book">
    </div> 
    <script defer src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thank you ! your help is really appreciated, I wil fix those and keep going at it !